# blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload template upload not working in zend framework 2

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, frameworks, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to get blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload working with zend framework 2.0.

When I put the form and ,  in the layout.phtml of in my view script (index.phtml), everything works!
When I create my form with the zend framework (Zend\Form\Form), the form show like it should but the template upload doesn't show anymore.

Can anybody help me? I tried to copy paste the script on the view, in the layout, .. doesn't work..

This is the content of my view script index.phtml

```
<div class="container center_piece place_need">
<!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
<form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div>
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <!-- The global file processing state -->
            <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- The extended global progress state -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
</form>
</div>
<!-- Content -->
...
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td>
        <span class="preview"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
        <strong class="error"></strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="size">Processing...</p>
        <div class="progress"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
            <button class="start" disabled>Start</button>
        {% } %}
        {% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
        {% } %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-download fade">
    <td>
        <span class="preview">
            {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
            {% } %}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="name">
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
        </p>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <div><span class="error">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
        {% } %}
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="     {%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>Delete</button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment yet.

Are you including all of the js files?  You need to still use the ones from the demo and make sure that all of the tags match.  Zend may change some of the tag names but it looked like the code above matched the demo.

```
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
```